# Payload Text (Data Field) Not Parsed for Retransmitted Packets?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I am using tshark to output the human-readable text from TCP packets. I do this with the data.text field. For example, my tshark.exe switches include:

```
-o data.show_as_text:TRUE -T fields -e data.text
```

This works just fine for most packets. The trouble comes when a packet is retransmitted by the sender. In these cases, data.text is always blank.

When analyzing the traffic in Wireshark, I see that retransmitted TCP frames (these are labeled as [TCP Retransmission] and include the note "This frame is a (suspected) retransmission") do not include the Data field at all - Wireshark does not reconstruct it (even though I have the parse data as text option enabled). Instead, these frames have a "Retransmitted TCP segment data" field (tcp.segment_data) which does not include any parsed text.

Is this a bug with tshark/wireshark? Why is the Data field not being constructed for these packets? Is there some other way for me to get the text from retransmitted TCP packets, or is my only option to manually decode the hex of tcp.segment_data for retransmitted packets?

The TCP connection I am monitoring frequently has retransmitted packets, so I am missing critical data at the moment.

Comment: Returning just to say I never did find a solution to this issue. Instead, I added some custom code to my project that manually decodes the payload into text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have TCP reassembly enabled?  Maybe try to disable it with `-o tcp.desegment_tcp_streams:FALSE`?  If that doesn't help, maybe there's a bug with the version of Wireshark you're using.  You could try [upgrading to the latest stable version](https://www.wireshark.org/#download) (2.6.1 as of this writing) and try again.  You could even try a recent [automated installer](https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/), if one is available for your OS or you could try [building Wireshark from sources](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/).  If the problem still persists, you could file a [Wireshark bug report](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/) along with a sample capture file to illustrate the problem.

You may also want to add a Wireshark display filter to your command-line to limit the output to only those packets that contain `data.text`, e.g. `-Y data.text`.

Refer to the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information about the `-Y` and other options.